# PHP how to stop class from inheriting namespace of parent class

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I am trying to write an autoloader function but running into an issue.  When I call my DBConnect class from inside my Product class it is inheriting the Product class namespace.

I cannot figure out how to use a "use" statement when autoloading the DBConnect class.  If I try to add a "use" statement after the include in my loader function, it throws an error.  So I keep getting a "Fatal error: Class 'App\Model\Entity\DbConnect' not found".  It should be using "App\Config\DBConnect".

It is my first autoloader I've built so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

bootstrap.php

```
require_once('Autoloader.php');
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Config/config.php';
spl_autoload_register('Core\Autoloader::loader');
```

Autoloader.php

```
namespace Core;
class Autoloader
{
  public static function loader( $class, $dir = null ) {

    if ( is_null( $dir ) )
        $direct  = array(
        '/Controller',
        '/Model/Entity',
        '/Model/Table',
        '/Config'
        );

    foreach ($direct as $dir){

        $scan = scandir(ROOTPATH . $dir);
        $classname = substr(strrchr($class, "\\"), 1);
        $classfile = $classname . '.php';

        foreach($scan as $file)
        {
            if(file_exists(ROOTPATH . $dir . '/' . $classfile)){
                include ROOTPATH . $dir . '/' . $classfile;
                goto xspot;
            }
        }
    }
    xspot:
  }
}
```

Product.php

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Config/config.php';
include ROOTPATH . '/Core/bootstrap.php';

class Product
 {
    public function __construct($conntype = 'MYSQLI') {
        $db = new DbConnect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect($conntype);
    }
```

DBConnect.php

```
namespace App\Config;
class DbConnect {
    function connect() {
        require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Config/config.php';   
        $conn = new \mysqli(DB_SERVER_MYSQLI, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_PORT);
          if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, remove line `require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Config/config.php';` from `Product.php` file as it already included in `bootstrap.php`
Secondly, add alias for `DbConnect` class as shown below:

***Product.php:***

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

include ROOTPATH . '/Core/bootstrap.php';
use App\Config\DbConnect as DbConnect;

...
$db = new DbConnect();
...
```

Comment: This gives me a new Fatal error: "Fatal error: Class 'App\Config\DBConnect' not found".

Comment: @ErichMosier, also try to not include `bootstrap.php` into `Product.php` at all, include only `config.php`

Comment: I am not clear how that would work.  If I dont include bootstrap.php, then I wouldnt be include the autoloader.  Am I missing something?  Or are you suggesting that I include bootstrap in the config file?

Comment: There was a misspelling that i didnt catch, but @diaraf below caught.  That is what caused the error.  But after fixing the misspelling (DbConnect rather than DBConnect) it is working.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add on top of

> Product.php

```
use App\Config;
```

or use:

```
$db = new App\Config\DbConnect();
```

because now object creation use bad namespace

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work.  I still get the same Fatal error

Comment: Actually I went back and took a closer look, and it actually gives me a different Fatal error: "Fatal error: Class 'App\Model\Entity\App\Config\DbConnect' not found"

Comment: there were mispelling in @RomanPerekhret answer
`use App\Config\DbConnect as DbConnect;`

Comment: That was it.  The misspelling was what was giving me the error when I tried Romans way.  Thanks for catching that.  Working now.